# How can I fix Highcharts error #13?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, handlebars.js

I use highchart so, the user can close and open the chart page and redraw the chart, in some case give me this error, how can I fix it, Thanks
Here is my code

```
 function populateGraph(graph1data1,graph1data2,id,time,bottomText,tickinterval){
$(function () {
  $('#'+id).highcharts({
      chart: {
          type: 'line'
      },
      xAxis: {
        tickWidth: 0,
        categories: ['1,2,3,4']
      },
      yAxis: {
        gridLineColor: '#fff',
          title: {
              text: ''
          },
          labels: {
              formatter: function() {
                  return '';
              }
          }              
      },
      navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
      series: [{
          name: 'This ',
          data: [1,2,3,4],
          color: '#1e71ef'     
      }, {
          name: 'Last ',
          data: [5,6,7,8],
          color:'#dfe0e1'
      }]
  });
});
}
}




       function loadOnlineDashboardChannel(channel){
          $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          dataType: 'html',
          data: {},
          url: "/companies/2/online_dashboard_channel",
          success: function(data, status){ 
          var obj = JSON.parse(data);
          var template_data = { 
            measures_list:   
              obj.measures         
          };
          $(function() { 
        var tmplHTML_measures = '{{#measures_list}} <div class="col-lg-11  col-lg-offset-1"><p class="indicator-title gray-bottom-border">{{name}}</br></p><div><p><span class="font30px">{{total}} </span> Total {{name}}<br><span class="green-text">{{increase}}%</span> from last <span class="metric_time"></span></p></div><div class="graph-header"><h3>{{this_interval}} </h3><p>New {{name}}</p><p class="percentage-graph green-text">{{percentag e}}%<p></div><div id={{graph_id}} class="graph"></div> </div>{{/measures_list}}';   
          Handlebars.render = function(tmpl, data){data = data || {};return                                                       Handlebars.compile(tmpl)(data);};  
      $("#template").empty().append(Handlebars.render(tmplHTML_measures,template_data) );
      var data_graph;
      for ( var i = 0; i < obj.measures.length; i++ ) {
        data_graph=obj.measures[i];
                      populateGraph(data_graph.this_interval_detail,data_graph.last_interval_detail,data_graph.graph_id,time,obj.bottom_graph_text,parseInt($('#timeframe-select').find(":selected").attr('interval')) );
      }              
     })


  },
  error: function(error) {

}
});

return this;
};
```

I use handlebar so in this part 
              
in
               var tmplHTML_measures
I create the div, in the for I call the function to draw the chart.

Thanks, I repeat sometimes it works perfectly and sometimes fail give me the error #13

Comment: Hi, I change my post and add some code, Sometimes work and sometimes not, the element id is ok, thanks

Comment: If highcharts is throwing that error than the jquery selector `$('#id')` is returning nothing.  My guess would have been that you didn't have your `.highcharts` call wrapped in a `$(function ()` but in the code above you have that.  Although you have an extra `}` at the end that doesn't belong.  Are you sure that the div id is unique?  `id="id"` seems like a poor naming convention.

Comment: yes my id is unique, I create it dynamically with a unique name, I use handlebar for that

Comment: So you need to have also this name in highcharts, the id of div need to be the same as name of selector which you use to create highcharts

Answer (score 15):

I faced the same error and what I got to know is that Error#13 occurs when HighCharts.js tries to access an element which is not present in the DOM.

How I fixed it?
I made sure that the HightCharts method is called only after my targeted element is created in the DOM. Bingo!!!! Everything worked fine.

Comment: Using Ionic, this means that you should not initialize the object in the constructor. You have to do it in ionViewDidLoad()

Comment: My issue was using a jQuery tag to reference an element, `'#mainChartDiv'` instead of just `'mainChartDiv'`.  The latter worked properly.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and fixed it using the correct container:

In my case I used the following:

```
// Use Meteor.defer() to create chart after DOM is ready:
Meteor.defer(function() {
  // Create standard Highcharts chart with options:
  Highcharts.chart('Charts', {
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 15,
            beta: 15,
            depth: 50,
            viewDistance: 25
        }
    },....
  }.....
}

Template.body.helpers({
  createChart: function () {...}
```

and in the HTML file:

```
<div id='Charts'>
    {{createChart}}
</div>
```

I found the fix from Highcharts: http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=15610

Regards.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12676571)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. :) Updating the answer

Comment: That's it we need to specifie inside wdiv id="" eather a barchart or linechar etc

Answer (score 4):

For me error was resolved when I placed the calling `script` after the HTML element.

Like;

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script>    
Highcharts.chart('container', {
// some script here
});
</script>
```

Also if you check on high chart site it says:

```
    This error occurs if the chart.renderTo option is misconfigured so that
Highcharts is unable to find the HTML element to render the chart in.
```

https://www.highcharts.com/errors/13

Answer (score 1):

Categories needs to be a collection, it was like this:

```
categories: xaxis
```

Change it to this:

```
categories: ['xaxis']
```

Some of the data fields need to be enclosed in single quotes like this:

```
data: 'blue'
```

Here is a fiddle without any errors for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/MVcBe/

Good luck with the rest. :)

ps I sometimes find it easier to edit a working fiddle from the highcharts site and adapt it to what you need. Like this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

Comment: Sorry that's not my issue, I receive xaxis like a parameter, I change the code with a static xaxis, my problem is related with the id, sometimes find the id and sometimes not, sometimes work perfectly and sometimes give me this error, the error #13 http://www.highcharts.com/errors/13

Comment: @Marion The code all looks good to me, no errors. Pls can you post your html?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit late to the party, but the default name for the container in Highcharts example was 'container'. The browser didn't seem to like that, name clash perhaps, changing to 'Chart' did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure "highcharts-more.js" is declared in your HTML.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I loaded script codes after document ready function, and it worked fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also run into the same error code, but in my case the reason was my data was too large to supported

Comment: This better post as a comment instead of an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: should i delete this anwser ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but none of the answers are really satisfactory in my opinion.

I would suggest checking to make sure the chart div exists before rendering the chart.

```
if($('#'+id).length){ $('#'+id).highcharts({});}
```

Comment: This would just not show the error in the console.

Comment: right, the error is thrown because the chart div is not present in the DOM. that's an issue that could be caused by any number of things. you can address that in an else statement if need be in whatever way is sufficient for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts ***cannot find the div with a specified*** `ID`. It usually occurs when the library is trying to render the chart, but the div is not yet created in the DOM.

You've to debug your code and try to find the information whether ***that element is present on your site*** at the moment when Highcharts need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

**Highcharts error #13** happens when the DOM element the HighCharts is referencing is not found.

Therefore, for you to debug this error, you have to check the DOM element availability before calling the the HighCharts callback function.. For your case try to console log the result of  **$('#'+id)**, If it's null make sure to recheck the html element id your referencing in the HighCharts and there should be no duplicate id.