# highgraphs chart not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have written some code to create and render a highcharts chart to my web page for each element in a map (@map).  I've been stumped for the past few hours trying to figure out where the problem in my code is.  So far I have the following code:

```
<script>
i = 0;
<% @map.each do |name, arr| %>
    graphTitle = String('<%= name %>')
    dataVector = <%= arr %>
    containerNum = 'container' + i
    var chart1 =  new Highcharts.Chart({ 
        chart: {
            renderTo: containerNum,
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
                stops: [
                    [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                    [1, 'rgb(240, 240, 255)']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 2,
            plotBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)',
            plotShadow: true,
            plotBorderWidth: 1
        },
        title : {
            text : graphTitle,
            x: -20
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Count'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        xAxis: {
            title :{
                text: 'Time (Hours)'
            },
            categories: <%= @timeArray.to_json%>
        },
        series: [{
            name: graphTitle,
            data :  dataVector
        }]
    });
    i = i + 1
<% end %>
```

I am confused because when I try to render the graphs individually (instead of iterating over the array) the graphs show up fine.  In addition, the javascript console displays no errors.  Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly?  My divs are named 'container0', 'container1', and 'container2' (and the map only has three elements).
Thanks!
EDIT: actually I just saw in the javascript console that it gives the error Uncaught Highcharts error #13: 
which means that there is something wrong in the renderTo: containerNum line

Comment: And when you use this code, what happen exactly ?

Comment: nothing shows up on the webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
After seeing error 13 in my console, I found the stackoverflow post:
[How can I fix Highcharts error #13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536233/how-can-i-fix-highcharts-error-13)
which pointed me to the correct answer.  I needed to wrap everything in a $(function(){