# Highcharts error #13 when trying to create a map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to create a Highcharts map but I can't get past the #13 error which states that the rendering container can't be found. All my other charts that's not a map chart works and it uses the same container class but I can't get maps to work at all.

Config object that gets passed to the `initMapChart` function (the map chart uses the same config as the normal charts):

```
highcharts.config = {
  chart: {
    type: highcharts.getTypeFromId(graph.type)
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stickyTracking: false,
        events: {
            click: function (e) {
                this.chart.myTooltip.refresh(e.point, e);
            }
        }
    },
    pie: {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
            return this.series.isLabelsVisible ? this.y : '';
        }
      },
      showInLegend: true
    },
    line: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    },
    area: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return this.series.isLabelsVisible ? this.y : '';
        }
      }
    },
    areaspline: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return this.series.isLabelsVisible ? this.y : '';
        }
      }
    },
    column: {
      stacking: false,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return this.series.isLabelsVisible ? this.y : '';
        }
      }
    },
    map: {
      mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
      joinBy: ['name'],
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  },
    toggleModify: false,
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: null,
        labels: {
      format: graph.span === 0 && graph.isTime && graph.childTarget === null ? '{value:%Y-%m-%d}' : '{value}'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    labels: {}
  },
  series: null,
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  }
};
```

I wait for the series to be created first before I try creating the charts, here is where I also set the `renderTo` property:

```
scope.$on('highchartsConfigUpdated', function(e, config) {

    initDataType();
    bindDataTypes();

    var target = element[0].querySelector('.highcharts-target');

    config.chart.renderTo = target;

    if (scope.graph.type === 6) {
      initMapChart(config);
    }
    else {
      initChart(config);
    }
  });
```

This function will be run for all charts with the type of 6, which means they're a map chart:

```
function initMapChart(config) {

    console.log(config.chart.renderTo);

    new Highcharts.Chart('Map', config, function(chart) {
      initLabels(chart);
      bindLabels(chart);
    });
  };
```

From the console log I get this which should  mean that it can in fact find the element:

```
<div id="chart-b2b2d164-b41c-40fc-a739-00cb1bc074ba" class="highcharts-target"></div>
```

So I think the issue is rather in the instantiation of the chart itself, how do you create a map chart without using jQuery?

Comment: Your question is answered here [Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536233/how-can-i-fix-highcharts-error-13)

Comment: I think that renderTo expects id of your container, not the container itself.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński No, the container can be either the element or the id.

Comment: You are right, sorry for that. I think that your constructor may be wrong. Try new Highcharts.Map(options) instead

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Mmmh, that seems to work but the map is unpannable, if adding panning: true to the config it only allows panning on the x-axis but if I look in examples the panning is always there even if nothing is specified in the config. I also can't use the Highmaps file since I'm already using Highcharts so the namespaces collide so I'm not sure on how to actually get this to work..

Comment: You may try using your charts with only highmaps library, look here http://jsfiddle.net/fywpfewh/