# How to fix "Highcharts error #13" on live chart? when i'm already insert DOMContentLoaded

Tags: php, ajax, charts, highcharts

i'm already follow this [link]: [How can I fix Highcharts error #13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536233/how-can-i-fix-highcharts-error-13) but still got an error on my highchart. i wanna make live highchart , this is my first time i make live chart and use highchart, can someone please help me to fix this problem ?

This is my dataPLLive.php

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/json");

$servername = "....0";
$username = "...s";
$password = "....";
$dbname = "...n";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$query = mysqli_query($conn,   ("SELECT a.`JAM`, AVG(a.PacketLoss) AVG
FROM (
SELECT `JAM`,`RNC`,`IPPATH_PM` AS PHB,`VS_IPPM_FORWORD_DROPMEANS` AS PacketLoss, `VSIPPMRttMeans` AS Latency, 'IPPM'
FROM `rnc_ippm_meas`
WHERE JAM=(SELECT MAX(JAM) FROM `rnc_ippm_meas`) AND `IPPATH_PM` LIKE '%AF31%'
UNION
SELECT `JAM`,`RNC`,`IPPOOL_PM`,`VSIPPOOLIPPMForwardDrop-Means`,`VSIPPOOLIPPMRttMeans`, 'IPPOOLPM'
FROM `rnc_ippool_ippm_meas` 
WHERE JAM=(SELECT MAX(JAM) FROM `rnc_ippool_ippm_meas`) AND `IPPOOL_PM` LIKE '%AF31%') a
GROUP BY a.`JAM`
LIMIT 10000 "));

if (!$query) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {            
    $value = $row['AVG'];

    $x = time() * 1000;
    $y = $value;

    $arr = array($x, $y);
    echo json_encode($arr);         
}

?>
```

this is json looks like

```
[1557373542000,"0.019680205406590504"]
```

then this is my html code

```
<script>
        var chart;
        function requestData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Controller/dataPLLive.php',
                success: function(point) {
                    var series = chart.series[0],
                        shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is 
                                                         // longer than 20

                    // add the point
                    chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

                    // call it again after one second
                    setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
                },
                cache: false
            });
        }
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

            chart = Highcharts.chart('loss_live', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline',
                    events: {
                        load: requestData
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Live random data'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150,
                    maxZoom: 20 * 1000
                },
                yAxis: {
                    minPadding: 0.2,
                    maxPadding: 0.2,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value',
                        margin: 80
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Random data',
                    data: []
                }]
            });        
        });
    </script>
```

and i follow https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data to make live chart.

is that something wrong with my code ? hope someone help me , Thanks btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code isn't showing where is the div `loss_live` but I assume it's really before the JS part.

The JSON should be like [1557373542000,0.019680205406590504]. No double-quote " on the value.

Change this line in the code from

```
$y = $value;
```

to

```
$y = floatval($value);
```

Comment: thanks for respon sir @Core972, and thanks for suggestion for my dataPLLive.php, but i still get error " highcharts error 3", yes the div before js

Comment: sir @Core972, how must the json outp for live chart btw ? like this [1557388562000,0.15689485657699218] , or [1557388562000,0.15689485657699218],[15573881212,0.1276177699218]

Comment: @LutfiMiftahudin, I don't see the difference between the 2 propositions except that the second have 2 data points. Did I miss something ?

Comment: sorry, for json output must the last time data (i use max for pick the lasttime data) or show all data on cureent date (select all on current date) , my english to bad sorry sir