# Highcharts error "Unable to find rendering div"

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts

I am currently learning Highcharts in Angular. Every time I create the Highcharts instance I get the following error: core.js:6479 ERROR Error: Highcharts error #13: [www.highcharts.com/errors/13/](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/13/)

This is how the ts file looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pie-chart',
  templateUrl: './pie-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pie-chart.component.css']
})
export class PieChartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {})
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {}
}
```

And this is the html file

```
<highcharts-chart
  id="container"
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [options]="chartOptions"
  style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block"
></highcharts-chart>
```

Before that I have created a chart and it worked just fine, now I am getting this nasty error. Can anybody help with that? Thank you

Comment: I think your constructor called before your HTML `<highcharts-chart>` tag load, Try to add some timeout just to check and confirm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536233/how-can-i-fix-highcharts-error-13#:~:text=Highcharts%20cannot%20find,to%20use%20it.

Comment: Hi, what do you want to achieve by putting inside the constructor variable chart? The constructor is usually used to retrieve some data as in this example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-data-from-service-2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts Are you familiar with the documentation for our Angular wrapper? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular