# HighCharts Error in Browser's Inspect Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I've multiple charts in an `ASP.NET MVC` view page and using **HighCharts** to render data dynamically from controller to view. So simply am doing this in the controller:

```
public JsonResult GetDataFromDatabase()
{
   return Json(aLst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In the view, doing something as follows:

```
<div id="containerDatabaseData">
</div>
```

**Script**:

```
    var baseTopsideModuleDry = [];
    var baseTopsideModulebaseOp = [];


    function LoadDynamicData(data) {
    //$('#containerDatabaseData').highcharts().destroy();

    if (data && data != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            baseTopsideModuleDry.push(data[i].BaseDry);
            baseTopsideModulebaseOp.push(data[i].BaseOp);
        }

        console.log("New Dataset " + baseTopsideModuleDry);
        console.log("New Dataset" + baseTopsideModulebaseOp);

        Highcharts.chart('containerDatabaseData', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: '@ViewBag.ProductName By Disciplines'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Structural Primary',
                    'Structural Secondary',
                    'Mechanical',
                    'Piping',
                    'Electrical',
                    'Instrument',
                    'Telecommunication',
                    'Safety',
                    'Architectural  ',
                    'Other/ Future Load  ',
                    'Live Load'
                ],
                crosshair: true
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Weight Data'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Dry',
                    data: baseTopsideModuleDry
                }, {
                    name: 'Operating',
                    data: baseTopsideModulebaseOp
                }]
        });
    }
}
```

But in some cases, I got this exception in the inspect element: **Highcharts error #13**, though I can understand the exception. But this occurs in some cases, not every time when I add or edit data in the front-end. Is there any appropriate workaround on this? Here are the screenshots that I encountered:

[Error 1](https://ibb.co/cJWZWpK) 
[Error 2](https://ibb.co/7ScqrvZ)

Comment: Error 13 means that the div you're targeting to render the chart in doesn't exist in the page. I would assume you've got a race condition between the JS rendering the chart and the DOM loading - in which case you just need to move your JS logic within a DOMContentLoaded event handler.

Comment: Is there any sample you can provide to avoid that or what I require to do @Rory McCrossan?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536233/how-can-i-fix-highcharts-error-13